# matplotlib window keeps being brought to the very front (how to set them to the back?)

Tags: python, opencv, animation, matplotlib

So I was playing around with the code I saw from github:
https://gist.github.com/Uberi/283a13b8a71a46fb4dc8

The goal is to use this real-time plotting structure to plot some info I retrieve from my real-time image so this is not my actual working code.

When I embed this structure into my actual working code(which includes openCV and some openCV GUI layout like Trackbars), It blocks me from using those GUI trackbars because the plotting window keeps popping up to the very front so my mouse couldn't press the button or drag a rectangle on my real time image.

Most of the questions I found relating to this topic is trying to get the windows to the front but I actually want to set the plotting windows to the back so it's kind of frustrating.

Would be great if you guys can give me some hint on this one.

```
import time, random
import math
from collections import deque

start = time.time()

class RealtimePlot:
    def __init__(self, axes, max_entries = 100):
        self.axis_x = deque(maxlen=max_entries)
        self.axis_y = deque(maxlen=max_entries)
        self.axes = axes
        self.max_entries = max_entries

        self.lineplot, = axes.plot([], [], "ro")
        self.axes.set_autoscaley_on(True)

    def add(self, x, y):
        self.axis_x.append(x)
        self.axis_y.append(y)
        self.lineplot.set_data(self.axis_x, self.axis_y)
        self.axes.set_xlim(self.axis_x[0], self.axis_x[-1] + 1e-15)
        self.axes.relim(); self.axes.autoscale_view() # rescale the y-axis

    def animate(self, figure, callback, interval = 50):
        import matplotlib.animation as animation
        def wrapper(frame_index):
            self.add(*callback(frame_index))
            self.axes.relim(); self.axes.autoscale_view() # rescale the y-axis
            return self.lineplot
        animation.FuncAnimation(figure, wrapper, interval=interval)

def main():
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    display = RealtimePlot(axes)
    #display.animate(fig, lambda frame_index: (time.time() - start, random.random() * 100))
    plt.show()

    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    display = RealtimePlot(axes)
    while True:
        display.add(time.time() - start, random.random() * 100)
        plt.pause(0.001)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: You could wrap the matplotlib figure in a Qt window ,(google Qt backends for matplotlib and there are plenty of examples). That will force matplotlib to update a figure, but the figure itself will be bounded into a Qt window easier to control.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After I looked into it, I actually added only one line of code to switch the backend to Qt5 and the window is now behaving!  

 I added this line before any plotting is done : plt.switch_backend('QT5Agg')

THANKS A LOT!!!